# How to Add a certain condition in where clause on the basis of some value

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE emp.id = @ID 
  AND emp.Name = @Name
  AND emp.isdeleted = @deleted
```

I want this last condition to be added on certain condition, I don't want to add the condition for `emp.isDeleted` until or unless `@deleted` value is passed into the SQL procedure.

If `@deleted` is `null`, I don't want `AND emp.isdeleted = @deleted` condition added to the query.

If `@deleted` is not null, it means it may have the either 1 or 0 then only I want `AND emp.isdeleted = @deleted` condition to added in the above SQL query.

Can someone please help me in this if this can be solved apart from dynamic query. since this is just a sample query to make the point but actual one is big enough to convert into dynamic query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically add or not add a particular condition to your `WHERE` clause; but you can be smart about how to specify that condition to handle both your cases.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE emp.id = @ID 
  AND emp.Name = @Name
  AND (@deleted IS NULL OR emp.isdeleted = @deleted)
```

Comment: thanks marc that really helped, its working as expected.